# Extending automorphisms of fields to matrix rings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

Suppose that $K$ is a field, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\sigma:K\to K$ is an automorphism of $K$. My question is, is there a way of defining an automorphism of the matrix ring $M_n(K)$ that is $\sigma$ when restricted to $K$.

I know that if $\sigma=id_K$ then the obvious way of extending $\sigma$ to $M_n(K)$ is to take an inner automorphism of $M_n(K)$, which will of course be identical on $K$. In fact, by the Skolem-Noether theorem, these are the only automorphisms of $K$ that are identical on $K$, i.e. the only $K$-algebra automorphisms of $M_n(K)$. But what if $\sigma\neq id_K$, can you think of any other way of extending it?

A good example is when $K=\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and $\sigma$ is the Frobenius automorphism, can you think of a ring automorphism $\varphi$ of $M_n(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ such that $\varphi(aI_n)=a^pI_n$ for all $a\in\mathbb{F_{p^2}}$.

Comment: Wouldn't just applying $\sigma$ to all coefficients of a matrix provide such an automorphism?

Comment: Just apply $\sigma$ componentwise?

Comment: Oh yes of course, so obvious. This died occur to me but for some reason I didn't think it would work. Thanks.